# Direct-init vs. list-init in array new-expression

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, initializer, new-expression

Basically, why is this valid:

`auto p1 = new int[10]{5};`

but this is not:

`auto p1 = new int[10](5);`

And more generally what are the rules for the new-expression initializer?

I found the following:

> — If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized (8.5). [ Note: If no initialization is performed, the object has an indeterminate value. — end note ]
>   — Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct- initialization.

So is the second case invalid because smth like `T((5))` is invalid (direct initialization from expression `(5)`)? Or what is the reason?

EDIT: well, my suggestion of `(())` thing seems dumb because I see no reason why that should only apply to array new-expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1st one is valid because of [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11),

> `new T { arg1, arg2, ... }`

and

> If T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.

`int[10]` is an array type which belongs to aggregate type, then [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) is performed,

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

So `auto p1 = new int[10]{5};` will create a pointer to array, whose first element is initialized as `5`, the remaining elements are initialized as `0`.

The 2nd one is [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), so `new int[10](5);` means initialize the array `int[10]` from a single `int` `5` directly; which is invalid.

In fact, for the [array new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Construction) you can't specify a non-empty parenthesized initializer.

> If type is an array type, an array of objects is initialized.
>
> - If initializer is absent, each element is default-initialized
> - If initializer is an empty pair of parentheses, each element is value-initialized.
> - If initializer is a brace-enclosed list of arguments, the array is aggregate-initialized. (since C++11)

So

```
auto p1 = new int[10];    // valid
auto p2 = new int[10]();  // valid
auto p3 = new int[10]{5}; // valid

auto p4 = new int[10](5); // invalid
```

#### EDIT

From the point view of the standard, as you quoted, [[expr.new]/18](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#18):

> A new-expression that creates an object of type T initializes that
>   object as follows:
>
> - If the new-initializer is omitted, the object is default-initialized ([dcl.init]). [ Note: If no initialization is performed, the object
>     has an indeterminate value. — end note ]

=> Applies for `auto p1 = new int[10];`, leads to default-initialization.

> - Otherwise, the new-initializer is interpreted according to the initialization rules of [dcl.init] for direct-initialization.

And [[dcl.init]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17):

> - (17.1) If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list or is = braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized.

=> Applies for `auto p3 = new int[10]{5};`, leads to list initialization, details are explained above.

> - (17.4) If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.

=> Applies for `auto p2 = new int[10]();`, leads to value initialization.

> - (17.5) Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.

=> Applies for `auto p4 = new int[10](5);`.

Comment: The shortness of this answer reflects very well the conciseness of the few tens of specification pages that describe the initialization recursive process!